# How do I stop my light flickering in a relay motion circuit?

Tags: solar-cell

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fND4Dm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My circuit has a motion detector that is only active when the solar panel has light upon it. (Night activated light) the output of the motion detector activates a relay which in turn activates a 230v light.

My issue is that in around 30% light the relay clicks on and off very fast as there isn't quite enough current to fully activate it causing the light to flicker quickly

I cannot modify the motion detector circuit only the wires going to each component.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post schematics of what you have access to? You need some hysteresis, but we'll have to see where to put the controller. Also, this is not good for your relay or light at the moment..!

Comment: Ive added it now

Comment: It sounds like you need a debouncer or latch.

Comment: @DominicBurton Thanks - I guess you have access to U1?

Comment: Add a comparator with hysteresis to the light level sensor signal path.

Comment: @awjlogan I have access to the wires joining it